# okay to put one coat of linseed oil over one coat of tung oil?

Tags: finishing

I'm in a situation where I had to take a piece from one shop to another as I moved cross country.

Yesterday I applied one coat of tung oil per the container's instructions.

The shop I am in this afternoon only has boiled linseed oil available. Are they similar enough that I can just apply the linseed oil as my second and final coat, or will there be an undesirable interaction between the two finishes?

For what it's worth, it is not that difficult for me to go out and get tung oil, but I'd rather not keep any more volatile inflammable finishes in my shop that I don't intend to use much, and I prefer linseed oil....

Comment: Congrats on the move. Yes you can freely intermix drying oils and pretty much any oil-based finishes, as well as apply many of them one over another without any harm. What's the on-pack recommended interval before the second coat of the tung oil? *"linseed oil as my second and final coat"* [Sorry, what?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/are-oil-finishing-and-oil-polishing-complementary/6858#6858) ;-)